How do I make a component both a child of BrowserRouter and a parent of all routes in React Router v6 (function syntax)?
In React Router v6, you can use components to define the router, like this:
export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <MyProvider>
      <Routes>
        ...
      </Routes>
    </MyProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

Where the MyProvider component is able to wrap all of the routes, while also being a child of the BrowserRouter component (so it is able to use React Router hooks like useNavigate()).
But how do you replicate this using the function syntax, i.e.,
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...
]);

export default () => (
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);


Create a layout route that renders the provider component and an Outlet as its child, and all the nested routes it wraps will be rendered into the outlet under the context it provides.
Example:
const MyProviderLayout = () => (
  <MyProvider>
    <Outlet />
  </MyProvider>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  ...
  {
    element={<MyProviderLayout />}
    children: [
      ... routes that access the `MyProvider` context ...
    ],
  },
  ... other routes ...
]);

export default () => (
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);


Thanks for the answer!  Do you know if this is the only way?  I'm using okta-react and I need the /login/callback route (and its LoginCallback component) to have access to the Security (MyProvider) context, but LoginCallback doesn't seem to work unless its route is registered at the top level (i.e. not via an Outlet).

@user1021 Can you clarify what you mean by "unless its route is registered at the top level" means exactly? Are you using any of the Data APIs, e.g. route loaders and actions? If you are not then you may not need to use a Data router, you can use the regular BrowserRouter like in your initial example. Since okta-react seems relevant do you mind updating your post to include all the relevant details and information?

By "registered at the top level", I meant placing the route's object in the outermost array, as opposed to any children array. I'm not using Data APIs, so I could just go with BrowserRouter. The reason I wanted to use createBrowserRouter instead was because the docs pushed that way, which makes me think it's more ideal and more future-proof. After a lot of research and testing, I'm 95% sure that what I'm trying to do is impossible because of the /login/callback constraint. I'll just wrap my provider around the router provider and use window.location instead of useNavigate.

@user1021 Does it need to be an "outer" component, or does the route just need to be a root-level route? Pathless layout routes don't contribute to the routing structure, but there may be some structural differences in the ReactTree is that's somehow an important distinction with the library you are using. I don't really see anything in the docs that explains this as a requirement though, just that whatever your login route path is just needs to be also defined in the okta config.

I just fixed it. The reason that my '/login/callback' route couldn't be a child of my '/' route was that my '/' component conditionally rendered <Outlet/> based on auth status, causing LoginCallback to not be mounted when it needed to be. I fixed it by making the '/' component solely the provider (like how your answer does it), and adding both '' and 'login/callback' paths as children of the '/' path. Then I just moved my previous '/' component (and its children) to this new '' path. So your answer is completely correct. Thanks for your help!
